# Not getting the expected output from OpenCL-kernel in MQL5

Tags: opencl, mql5, metatrader5

Here is the function that I am trying to work with:

```
#define SIZE_X 512
#define SIZE_Y 512

int   cl_ctx;
int   cl_prg;
int   cl_krn;
int   cl_mem;

float ExponentialMA( const int     position,
                     const int     period,
                     const double  prev_value,
                     const double &price[]
                     )
{
//---
   float result[]; 
   ArrayResize(result,1);
   float pr=2.0/(period+1.0);
   Print( "Reality:  :) ", (float)price[position]*pr+prev_value*(1-pr) );

   if (  period > 0 )     //--- calculate value
   {        
     //--- initializing OpenCL objects
     if((cl_ctx=CLContextCreate(CL_USE_GPU_ONLY))==INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
        Print("OpenCL not found: ", GetLastError() );
        return(0);
     }

     string str;     
     if((cl_prg=CLProgramCreate(cl_ctx,cl_src,str))==INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
        CLContextFree(  cl_ctx ); Print("OpenCL program create failed: ", str);
        return(0);
     }

     if((cl_krn=CLKernelCreate(cl_prg,"Calculation"))==INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
        CLProgramFree(  cl_prg );
        CLContextFree(  cl_ctx ); Print("OpenCL kernel create failed");
        return(0);
     }

     if((cl_mem=CLBufferCreate(cl_ctx,SIZE_X*SIZE_Y*sizeof(int),CL_MEM_READ_WRITE))==INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
        CLKernelFree(   cl_krn );
        CLProgramFree(  cl_prg );
        CLContextFree(  cl_ctx ); Print("OpenCL buffer create failed");
        return(0);
     }

     int  offset[2]={0,0};
     int  work  [2]={SIZE_X,SIZE_Y};

     CLSetKernelArg(    cl_krn, 0, period );
     CLSetKernelArg(    cl_krn, 1, (float) price[position] );
     CLSetKernelArg(    cl_krn, 2, (float)prev_value );
     CLSetKernelArgMem( cl_krn, 3, cl_mem );

     Print( period, "  ", price[position], "  ", prev_value );

     //--- rendering the frame
     CLExecute(         cl_krn, 2, offset, work );
     CLBufferRead(      cl_mem, result );

     ArrayPrint( result );

     CLBufferFree(      cl_mem );
     CLKernelFree(      cl_krn );
     CLProgramFree(     cl_prg );
     CLContextFree(     cl_ctx );
  }
  //---
  return( result[0] );
}
```

This is the `cl_src`:

```
const string cl_src= 

"__kernel void Calculation(int period,                            \r\n"
                           "float price,                          \r\n"
                           "float prev_value,                     \r\n"
                           "__global float *result)               \r\n"
"{                                                                \r\n"
"   float pr=2.0/(period+1.0);                                    \r\n"
"   printf(\"Functional value: %f\",price);                       \r\n"
"   result[0]=price*pr+prev_value*(1-pr);                         \r\n"
"}                                                                \r\n";
```

The output expected is the value of the `Exponential Moving average` which must be some value after process. But in the output I am getting the value as `0.0000`.

Which is not the expected value.

Even the **`printf()`** function in the `cl_src` not giving the output. My guess is that the value is not received by the process. I don't understand what I have missed.
Kindly, suggest me what I can do. Or is there anything I did in memory management? How I can make it multiple core workable??

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL-kernel, the very same as CUDA/GPU-kernel, code is compiled and transferred and "remotely" executed there - inside the OpenCL-device. So, unless some platform-specific tricks are present as an OpenCL-driver extension, there is no way to make the "remote"-execution engine "deliver"-**`printf()`**-output(s) back into the principally dis-connected / de-synchronised asynchronous heterogeneous distributed computing ecosystem ( the MetaTrader Terminal platform has nothing to do with the "remote" process-flow and vice-versa ).

```
 if (  INVALID_HANDLE == ( cl_prg = CLProgramCreate( cl_ctx,
                                                     cl_src,
                                                     str
                                                     )
                           )
       )
  {                        Print( "CLProgramCreate() failed: ", str );
                                   CLContextFree( cl_ctx );
                           return( 0 );
  }
  Print( "DEBUG[OpenCL]: compiler log:\nDEBUG[OpenCL]INFO:[[", str, "]]\n" );
  ...
```

### So, better avoid any in-kernel "*printing*"  <sup>unless platform-validated tools available</sup>

Next the interfacing: OpenCL / MQL5 inter-operability is documented to use exclusively the ***buffer***-mapped tools for moving data-in and returning data-out.

---

### The best next step:

Re-compile the simplified OpenCL kernel without any printing and re-test the simplest ever step: move just a plain simple value ( using as simple value as -1. ) into a single array cell, so as to validate the workflow and all the call-signature matches first, before moving into more details, ok?

```
const string
cl_src = "__kernel void Calculation(          int    period,     \r\n" // [0]__GPU_call-interface_ORDINAL
         "                                    float  price,      \r\n" // [1]__GPU_call-interface_ORDINAL
         "                                    float  prev_value, \r\n" // [2]__GPU_call-interface_ORDINAL
         "                           __global float *result      \r\n" // [3]__GPU_call-interface_ORDINAL
         "                           )                           \r\n"
         "{                                                      \r\n"
         "     result[0] = -1;                                   \r\n"
         "}                                                      \r\n";
```

---

```
...                                                               // OpenCL SETUP
// -----------------------------------------------<ASYNC>.LAUNCHER
CLExecute(         cl_krn, 2, offset, work );
// -----------------------------------------------<ASYNC>.MONITOR
do
while ( getOpenCL_KernelExecutionSTATE( cl_krn ) >     CL_COMPLETE );
// -----------------------------------------------<ASYNC>.COMPLETE
CLBufferRead(      cl_mem, result );
// -----------------------------------------------<ASYNC>.TRY-READ-MAPPING-BUFFER
```

---

```
int getOpenCL_KernelExecutionSTATE(                 int aKernelHANDLE = 0 )
{   int    cl_KernelExecutionSTATE = CLExecutionStatus( aKernelHANDLE );
    switch(cl_KernelExecutionSTATE )
    { 
      case( CL_COMPLETE  ): Print( "DEBUG[OpenCL]:program[, aKernelHANDLE, "] complete." );
                            return( CL_COMPLETE );

      case( CL_RUNNING   ): Print( "DEBUG[OpenCL]:program[, aKernelHANDLE, "] in running phase." );
                            return( CL_RUNNING );

      case( CL_SUBMITTED ): Print( "DEBUG[OpenCL]:program[, aKernelHANDLE, "] submitted for execution." );
                            return( CL_SUBMITTED );

      case( CL_QUEUED    ): Print( "DEBUG[OpenCL]:program[, aKernelHANDLE, "] waiting in a queue." );
                            return( CL_QUEUED );

      case( WRONG_VALUE  ): Print( "DEBUG[OpenCL]:program[, aKernelHANDLE, "] returned Error upon last CLExecutionStatus() call." );
                            return( WRONG_VALUE );

      default:              Print( "Ought never get here... Check updated MQL5 documentation." );
                            return( WRONG_VALUE );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what these `2`, `offset' and `work` are in `CLExecute(         cl_krn, 2, offset, work );`. Actually when I used the same in my program, I got output as zero (0) means no output at all. But when I neglect and used only`CLExecute(cl_krn);` then the program worked well and gave output. Why my program is not capable of using multiple cores of the GPU? I do not understand.

Comment: Yes, I can. Feel free to [+1] reward and Accept this and other previously provided useful and serious Answers and may open another Question of your choice. This is the way how StackOverflow works. Having an indeed plenty of not rewarded and not yet accepted Answers under your Questions **is a red-flag warning.**

Comment: Yes your answer is worth accepting, but I haven't got the reason for my zeros as output when I run the program with the help of work and offset. Without the variables, I am getting the answer.